# How can i update react-native-map marker smoothly as location changes?

Tags: react-native, google-maps, geolocation, google-maps-markers, react-native-maps

I am having issues animating the map marker on react-native-maps application. the marker stays in the center and do not move with the blue dot. and the map screen changes abruptly.

I am using the android emulator route simulator to simulate moving around.

What I really want to achieve is to update the map marker on the map screen smooothly just like the default blue dot is doing as the current location changes.

This is what I've tried:
**MapScreen.js**

```
const [
    mapRef,
    requestLocationPermission,
    position,
    watchId,
    subscribeLocationLocation,
    getOneTimeLocation,
    setPosition,
  ] = useLocation();
  const [darkMode, setDarkMode] = useState(theme.dark);

  useEffect(() => {
    requestLocationPermission();
    subscribeLocationLocation(user._id);

    return () => {
      Geolocation.clearWatch(watchId);
    };
  }, []);

  const toggleDarkMode = () => setDarkMode(!darkMode);
  console.log(darkMode);

  return (
    <View style={styles(colors).mapContainerStyles}>
      <StatusBar backgroundColor="transparent" translucent={true} />
      <View style={styles(colors).container}>
        <MapView
          userInterfaceStyle={darkMode ? 'dark' : 'light'}
          key={darkMode}
          ref={mapRef}
          region={position}
          onRegionChange={() => position}
          onRegionChangeComplete={position => setPosition(position)}
          style={styles(colors).mapStyle}
          initialRegion={position}
          customMapStyle={darkMode ? mapStyle : {}}
          showsUserLocation={true}
          showsMyLocationButton={true}
          followsUserLocation={true}
          showsCompass={true}
          scrollEnabled={true}
          zoomEnabled={true}
          pitchEnabled={true}
          rotateEnabled={true}>
          <Marker
            draggable
            coordinate={{
              latitude: position.latitude,
              longitude: position.longitude,
            }}
            onDragEnd={e =>
              Alert.alert(JSON.stringify(e.nativeEvent.coordinate))
            }
            pinColor="green"
            title={'Test Marker'}
            description={`${position.latitude}, ${position.longitude}`}
          />
        </MapView>
        <View style={styles(colors).darkModeStyles}>
          <DefaultText
            textColor={darkMode ? 'white' : 'black'}
            textStyle={styles(colors).darkModeTextStyles}
            bold={true}
            textString={`${darkMode ? 'Light' : 'Dark'} Mode`}
          />
          <Switch
            trackColor={{false: '#767577', true: '#81b0ff'}}
            thumbColor={darkMode ? '#f5dd4b' : '#f4f3f4'}
            ios_backgroundColor="#3e3e3e"
            onValueChange={toggleDarkMode}
            value={darkMode}
          />
          {/* <Button onPress={toggleDarkMode} title="Dark Mode" /> */}
        </View>
      </View>
      <View style={styles(colors).informationStyles}>
        <Button
          onPress={() => getOneTimeLocation()}
          title="Get current location"
        />
        <Information navigation={navigation} />
      </View>
    </View>
  );
};
```

**useLocation.js**

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';

import {PermissionsAndroid, Platform} from 'react-native';
import Geolocation from '@react-native-community/geolocation';
import socket from './socket';

export default function useLocation() {
  //   const [currentLongitude, setCurrentLongitude] = useState(0);
  //   const [currentLatitude, setCurrentLatitude] = useState(0);
  const [locationStatus, setLocationStatus] = useState('');
  const [watchId, setWatchId] = useState(null);

  const mapRef = React.useRef(null);

  const [position, setPosition] = useState({
    latitude: 9.077751,
    longitude: 8.6774567,
    latitudeDelta: 0.0922,
    longitudeDelta: 0.0421,
  });

  const requestLocationPermission = async () => {
    console.log('REQUESTING LOCATION PERMISSION!!!!!');
    if (Platform.OS === 'ios') {
      getOneTimeLocation();
      // subscribeLocationLocation();
    } else {
      console.log('INSIDE OF ANDROID PLATFORM');
      try {
        const granted = await PermissionsAndroid.request(
          PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
          {
            title: 'Location Access Required',
            message: 'This App needs to Access your location',
          },
        );
        if (granted === PermissionsAndroid.RESULTS.GRANTED) {
          console.log('ANDROID PERMISSION HAS BEEN GRANTED!!!');
          //To Check, If Permission is granted
          getOneTimeLocation();
          // subscribeLocationLocation();
        } else {
          setLocationStatus('Permission Denied');
        }
      } catch (err) {
        console.warn(err);
      }
    }
  };

  const getOneTimeLocation = () => {
    console.log('GETTING ONE TIME LOCATION!!!');
    setLocationStatus('Getting Location ...');
    Geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
      //Will give you the current location
      pos => {
        console.log('===============================');
        console.log(pos.coords);
        console.log('===============================');
        const crd = pos.coords;
        setLocationStatus('You are Here');
        //getting the Latitude from the location json
        // setCurrentLongitude(crd.longitude);
        // //Setting state Longitude to re re-render the Longitude Text
        // setCurrentLatitude(crd.latitude);

        console.log('SETTING NEW POSITION GOTTEN FROM DEVICE!!!');
        setPosition({
          latitude: crd.latitude,
          longitude: crd.longitude,
          latitudeDelta: 0.0922,
          longitudeDelta: 0.0421,
        });

        mapRef.current?.animateToRegion(position);
        //Setting state Latitude to re re-render the Longitude Text
      },
      error => {
        setLocationStatus(error.message);
        console.log(error);
      },
      {enableHighAccuracy: true, timeout: 25000, maximumAge: 3600000},
    );
  };

  const subscribeLocationLocation = userId => {
    console.log('SUBSCRIBING TO LOCATION!!!');
    const watchid = Geolocation.watchPosition(
      pos => {
        console.log(pos);
        // setLocationStatus('You are Here');
        const crd = pos.coords;
        console.log(crd);

        setPosition({
          latitude: crd.latitude,
          longitude: crd.longitude,
          latitudeDelta: 0.0922,
          longitudeDelta: 0.0421,
        });
        // mapRef.current?.animateToRegion(position);
        //Setting state Latitude to re re-render the Longitude Text

        if (
          position.latitude == crd.latitude &&
          position.longitude == crd.longitude
        ) {
          console.log('Same position as before');
        } else {
          socket.emit('updateLocation', {position, userId});
        }
      },
      error => {
        setLocationStatus(error.message);
      },
      {
        enableHighAccuracy: true,
        distanceFilter: 5000,
        interval: 5000,
        fastestInterval: 2000,
      },
    );

    setWatchId(watchid);
  };

  return [
    mapRef,
    requestLocationPermission,
    position,
    watchId,
    subscribeLocationLocation,
    getOneTimeLocation,
    setPosition,
  ];
}
```

[image]

Comment: Can you please point us to the part of your code that is responsible for the movement of the camera? From what I can see, you are just updating the camera once the state of the current location changes. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, that is correct

Comment: Instead of changing the state of the current location alone, how about you call `animateCamera` whenever the current location changes? Changing the state alone would snap it to place but the react native maps have a built in method for animating the camera. https://github.com/react-native-maps/react-native-maps/blob/master/docs/mapview.md#:~:text=current%20camera%20configuration.-,animateCamera,-camera%3A%20Camera%2C

Comment: alright, thanks a lot. it's been fixed.

Comment: @Yrll If you can, please create an answer and the OP will mark it as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

check-in  mapview

```
onUserLocationChange={async (e) => {{/* you can her update the marker but that will make the blue point always appear if u want to remove it u can set  showsUserLocation={false} and use  const cordsMarkerLocation = await Location.watchPositionAsync(
          { accuracy: Location.Accuracy.High },
          (location) => {
            setLocationMarker(location.coords);
          }
        );*/}}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).